# Populating BRAM using a .coe file on Xilinx Alveo U280

Tags: fpga, xilinx, vivado, bram

I am new to the world of FPGAs.

I am using Xilinx Alveo U280. While performing a task in my research project, I tried to populate the BRAM with 0's but the simulation shows 'Z', 'ZZ', and 'ZZZZ' as input. What do they mean and how to correct them?

[image]

My .coe file looks like this:

[image]

I didn't use a code to instantiate and populate the BRAM but instead went ahead with "Create Block Design" in IP Integrator in Vivado. I ran behavioral simulation for a simple read operation. I was hoping to get the same output as the input but it turns out the input itself isn't fed properly..

[image]

Comment: Please post relevant code

Comment: @VoltageSpike I didn't use a code to instantiate and populate the BRAM but instead went ahead with "Create Block Design" in IP Integrator in Vivado.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the test bench to simulate the BRAM module. Just clicking on `run behavioral simulation` won't simulate the module.

Even though you are just reading from the BRAM, but the signals such as `addra[6:0]`, `dina`, `clka`, `ena` and `wea[0:0]` are not being driving by any logic and that is because there is not test bench. But still the positive thing is, you can see zeros on `douta_0[15:0]` port which indicates that the BRAM has been populated with your coefficient file.